# WPF-XAML window in Winforms Application

Tags: wpf, winforms, window

I have a Winforms application coded in VS C# 2008 and want to insert a WPF window  into the window pane of Winforms application.

Could you explain me how this is done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx).

```
ElementHost es = new ElementHost();
es.HostContainer.Children.Add(screen); // where screen is your wpf window or user control

es.Dock = Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill; // probably want to fill the element host. Not necessary
somePanel.Controls.Add(es); // add the element host to a panel on your Winform or the form itself
```

Hope that helps